# VBA simple code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmdplay_click()

    LblGameName.Caption = "Hello! And welcome to Unicorn Adventure Extream! Are you excited?"
    CmdExit.Caption = "no"
    CmdPlay.Caption = "yes"
    If CmdPlay = True Then
        LblGameName.Caption = "As you should be!! Welcome to Unicopitopia! Will you please enjoy your stay?"
    ElseIf CmdExit = True Then
        LblGameName.Caption = "You have angered the unicorn!! She ripped out your heart and devoured it! Bad Luck! Much Blood!"
    End If

End Sub
```

I dont understand why my label isn't changing when i press yes or no?

Comment: In your cmdPlay clause, you refer to "lblnamegame". Did you mean "LblGameName"?

Comment: Oh.. oops! yes! thank you! Ive been messing with it a lot, it still doesnt work after i have fixed that though

Comment: It's hard to solve the problem without more details. You should give a description of what the form looks like, what you are doing, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. Otherwise the best we can do is look for typos.

Comment: i apologize i am really new to this. The form just has two buttons and a label, it supposed to lead you through the game. Clicking play gives you and option to answer the question yes or no. I want, when you press no to end the game and have the label display the text. When you press yes i want the same thing but different text adn the game to continue. What happens when i press yes or no is nothing changes. The cmdplay and cmdexit say false when i put in a break point. So i thought clicking them would change them to true. when make them 'if cmdexit = false' the label changes automatically

Comment: I changed your typo for your so all the LblGameName's match.  I also indented your If Statements results for better readability.  Check my answer below to deal with the other issues.  For example, you don't need to worry about renaming the cmdButton Captions.  Set those in the properties on the Object Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your example.

You will want to have your buttons named and have the text in them stay the same.  One could be cmdYes, and the other cmdExit.  Then have click events associated with those buttons.  To get that to happen, just double click on the button in the Form Object Designer mode, and it will bring up the code and generate a click event.

You definitely have things misnamed, according to your earlier naming.

I would have the Lbl you have named something like txtMessage, and have it as a locked textbox. You can set the background color of the textbox to match the UserForm color. Then just set the text of it to update with whatever printout you are trying to achieve.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    txtMessage.Text =  "Hello! And welcome to Unicorn Adventure Extreme! Are you excited?"

End Sub
```

Then have separate events for your buttons.

```
Private Sub cmdExit_click()

    Dim exitMessage As String

    exitMessage = "You have angered the unicorn!! She ripped out your heart and devoured it! Bad Luck! Much Blood!"
    txtMessage.Text = exitMessage

    MsgBox("Game Over, Goodbye") ' or whatever else you want to have happen.  
    Unload Me      'You could unload the form here.

End Sub
```

A separate event for each button.

```
Private Sub cmdYes_click()

    Dim YesMessage As String

    YesMessage = "As you should be!! Welcome to Unicopitopia! Will you please enjoy your stay?"
    txtMessage.Text = YesMessage

    'Call some other subroutine that launches your game.
End Sub
```